# Using MVVM instead of main window for the following code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I'm using the following code which is copy pasted from the main window which was working as expected ,

- I have created View which is user control and put the code of the
  code from the main window XAML
- In the View model I put reference for the User model
- In the user control I put the code for from the the main window which
  is related to the event handlers  for example the
  DropText_PreviewDragEnter & listbox_SelectionChanged

*Currently I have 2 issues in the User Control which Im not sure how to overcome...*

**1.** Errors in the user control for all the occurrence of the ListBox (for example from listbox_SelectionChanged  ystem.Windows.Controls.ListBox.**SelectedItems**.Count > 0 . the Selected items are marked at red with the following error

"cannot access non-static property SelectedItems item source in static context". ,not sure what is the reason since in the main window it was the same as static.

**2.** Since I have copied the code from the main window there is references to user object in the user controlwhich I believe is not acceptable in MVVM ,how should I change it ? for example

```
var mySelectedItem = System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.SelectedItem as User;
```

or

```
bool remove = _UsersList.Remove((User) System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.SelectedItem);
```

***Here is the code.***

I will appreciate your help !

The view model

```
public partial class ModelView : UserControl
{
    private const string DRAG_SOURCE = "DragSource";

    public ModelView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ModelView();
    }



    //Drag Over from text box to List box


    private void ListBox_PreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        object dragSource = e.Data.GetData(DRAG_SOURCE);
        if (dragSource != null && dragSource is TextBox)
        {
            (dragSource as TextBox).Text = String.Empty;
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat).ToString()) && dragSource is TextBox)
        {
            _UsersList.Add(new User {Name = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat).ToString()});
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    }
}
```

The Xaml is

```
    <TextBox x:Name="name1"  
              AcceptsReturn="True"
              AllowDrop="True" 
              PreviewDragEnter="DropText_PreviewDragEnter"
              PreviewDrop="DropText_PreviewDrop"
              PreviewMouseDown="DropText_PreviewMouseDown"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="360,70,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70"/>
```

....

The model view

```
internal class ModelView
{
    private ObservableCollection<User> _UsersList = new ObservableCollection<User>();

    public ObservableCollection<User> UserList
    {
        get { return _UsersList; }
    }

    public void InitUsers()
    {
        _UsersList.Add(new User {Name = "fff"});

        //Sort the User collection
        ICollectionView usersView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_UsersList);
        usersView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));

    }

}
```

Comment: Erm, sorry but if you are inheriting from a `UserControl` then that is a `View` not a `ViewModel`. This isn't MVVM (yet) but a half way there pattern. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx for how MVVM should be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@phil correctly noted that you can't access the `ListBox` like this:

```
System.Windows.Controls.ListBox
```

What he failed to mention is that you shouldn't access a `ListBox` at all if you're using MVVM. Clearly you're *not* using MVVM now, but if you want to, then I would recommend that you read up on it so that you can get the full benefit from it. Just having a view and a view model does *not* mean that you're using MVVM.

In MVVM, we manipulate *data*, not *UI controls*. Therefore, you need to create a `SelectedItem` property in your view model and bind that to the `ListBox.SelectedItem` property and then you'll always have access to the item that is selected:

```
public User SelectedItem { get; set; } // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged here

...

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
```

Now you can do something with the selected item like this:

```
string selectedItemName = SelectedItem.Name;
```

Comment: Since Im using drag and drop (see the text boxes xaml) I need to put the code of the events such DropText_PreviewDragEnter
in the user control,otherwise I'll get errors!!! ,how would you do it if you dont want to break the mvvm ,please provide example

Comment: Any event can be handled in an MVVM way by wrapping it in an Attached Property... here is a simple [example tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/478643/Mouse-Event-Commands-for-MVVM).

Comment: Can't agree more with you here @Sheridan.  `Model`s and `ViewModel`s should not know anything about the UI layer

Answer (score 3):

You already have two answers explaining why the first issue happend in [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958963/how-to-bind-the-viewmodel-to-view). And follwoing points are what @Will said in comment as a mess in MVVM implementation that I can see in your codes :

2. `UsersList` in the model view is a **Model** as in **Model**-View-ViewModel.
3. And the model view it self is a **ViewModel** as in Model-View-**ViewModel**
4. Then what you call view model is actually a **View** in Model-**View**-ViewModel point of view. It inherits `UserControl` and `UserControl` is a view, no difference from `Window` or `Page`, etc. They're all View. And even if we agree to call it view model, then it violated MVVM principle everywhere, because view model shouldn't have reference to View/UI control object.

Not directly answering your question, but I hope you get a better prespective on MVVM pattern.

Comment: Since Im using drag and drop (see the text boxes xaml) I need to put the code of the events such DropText_PreviewDragEnter in the user control,otherwise I'll get errors!!! ,how would you do it if you dont want to break the mvvm ,please provide example

Answer (score 1):

you have to access your listbox by

```
yourListBoxName.SelectedItems.Count > 0
```

you can't access it by

```
System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.SelectedItems.Count
```

same for

```
var mySelectedItem = System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.SelectedItem as User;
```

use the following instead

```
var mySelectedItem = yourListBoxName.SelectedItem as User;
```